# How to formulate a constraint in pulp involving indicator variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pulp

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898987/how-to-add-indicator-constraints-in-pulp-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579663/pulp-python-how-to-formulate-constraint-with-a-binary-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557173/triggering-a-binary-variable-based-on-the-values-of-another-variable)

but couldn't generalize solutions to my problem or there were no correct answers.

If I want a binary variable to turn off and on based on another variable selection so that when lpSum(some_var) = 0 then indicator_var must be 0 and when lpSum(some_var) > 0 then indicator_var must be 1 where lpSum(some_var) will never be grater than 5, then if I write:

```
for j in some_list:
    prob += lpSum(some_var[i, j] for i in some_other_list) <= indicator_var[j] * 5
```

this ensures that indicator_var is 1 if lpSum > 0 which is fine, but it does not guarantee that indicator_var is 0 if lpSum = 0.
Hopefully it's clear what I want to achieve, if not please let me know so I can clarify further with more concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn’t say what type of variable you are summing, but assuming non-negativity, this should work:

```
prob += lpSum(...) >= indicator_var[...]
```

Edit:  The above should be used in conjunction with the constraint you already have above (2 constraints needed to enforce the inference you want).  So also:

```
prob += lpSum(...) <= indicator_var[...] * 5
```

Comment: Yes I am summing a binary variable. Not sure how this can solve the problem though.  I would need an indicator_var to take the value 1 if lpSum(…) > 0 and 0 if lpSum(…) = 0. In your example, If lpSum(…) = 3, indicator_var[…] can still be 0. Thanks for input!

Comment: I wasn't clear in my answer.  I was assuming you would still implement the constraint you already had...  the pair is needed.  :)